# Notification Error FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Tags: java, android

I am currently recieving an eror i have not experienced before. I want a basic notification to show when AlarmReciever.java is executed. The error is for FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.

Can anyone help with a solution?

Thank you!

**AlarmReceiver:**

```
package servicealarmdemo.test2;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID=1;
NotificationManager notificationManager;
Notification myNotification;
private final String myBlog = "http://android-er.blogspot.com/";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(myBlog));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, myIntent,Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle("Exercise of Notification!")
            .setContentText("http://android-er.blogspot.com/")
            .setTicker("Notification!")
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();

    notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);
}

}
```

Comment: just read your logcat(stacktrace) carefully it will tell you what you have to do exactly. If you are starting some activity on notification fire then it will need to add a flag to startActivity which is above mentioned by you. Simply you need to add this flag to your intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static PendingIntent getActivity (Context context, int requestCode, Intent intent, int flags){
    ...
}
```

The last parameter May be `FLAG_ONE_SHOT, FLAG_NO_CREATE, FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT, FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`, or any of the flags as supported byIntent.fillIn() to control which unspecified parts of the intent that can be supplied when the actual send happens.
So your code could be like this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(myBlog));
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, myIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I just updated it with the code you provided, but the alarm crashes when it tries to run the notification.

Comment: The same problem as before updated? Show the logcat if possible.

Comment: Thanks again for replying. It actually doesn't show any error, which is more confusing and stopping me figuring out what the issue is: http://i.imgur.com/RTDf1KS.png

Comment: I have attached MainActivity to the original post, just in case anything can be seen there, or should this intent be added their rather than AlarmReceiver?

Comment: I tyied your code and find out that you didn't `setIcon` for your notification.Maybe that is why it crashes.